# Как правильно удалить дубликаты в многомерном массиве?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть такой массив `$array`:

```
array(100) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(12345)
    ["date"]=>
    int(277345533)
  [1]=>array(2)
    //такие же ключи(id, date)
  [2]=>array(2)
    //такие же ключи(id, date)
  [3]//... ну и так далее
```

Мне нужно убрать(или присвоить `null`), все элементы, у которых совпадает `id`(т.е. Если есть 3 элемента с одинаковым `id`, должен остаться только один). Я пробовал применять функцию `array_unique()`:

```
$newarr=array_unique($array);
```

Но в массиве `$newarr` я получаю всего пару элементов из 100, хотя повторений одно-два, а то и вообще нет. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Так нужно убрать все элементы или оставить один (и с каким его значением оставить: какой из них)?

Comment: @RomanGrinyov нужно убрать все элементы, у которых одинаковый `id`, чтобы остался только один(например, первый). Т.е. если повторяется элемент с одинаковым id 4 раза - 3 элемента удалятся, в результате останется один.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно, вам стоит передавать в качестве второго параметра `array_unique` константу `SORT_REGULAR` вот так

```
$newarr=array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Согласно [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php), по умолчанию используется `SORT_STRING`, который сравнивает элементы как строки.

Если же вам нужно получать `unique` результаты только учитывая одно поле массива `id`, можете воспользоваться такой функцией, которая тоже [есть](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php#116302) в документации

```
function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) { 
$temp_array = array(); 
$i = 0; 
$key_array = array(); 

foreach($array as $val) { 
    if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) { 
        $key_array[$i] = $val[$key]; 
        $temp_array[$i] = $val; 
    } 
    $i++; 
} 
return $temp_array; 
}
```

вызываете вот так

`$newarr=unique_multidim_array($array, 'id');`

Comment: Спасибо, `SORT_REGULAR` - это то, что мне нужно. Теперь всё работает отлично.

Answer (score 0):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$arr = array(
  array(
    'id' => 12345,
    'date' => 277345533
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 12345,
    'date' => 277345533
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 12345,
    'date' => 277345533
  )
);
$arr = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $arr)));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```